# How to integrate LogAnalyticsWorkSpace with Data Factory using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics

Using Terraform how to deploy Azure Data Factory, along with Monitoring using LogAnalyticsWorkSpace?

Comment: Can you share more details on what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you want a basic setup of of deploying Azure data factory and route its logs/metrics from Azure Monitor to a Azure Log analytics Workspace, below Terraform code is tested. Let me know if you'd want to further include anything specific.

Here is what my `main.tf` looks like:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features { }
}

#Manages an Azure Data Factory (Version 2).

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examplesa"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
}


#create log analytics workspace

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "acctest-01"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}


#Manages an ADF logs within Azure Monitor with Log Analytics Workspace.

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  target_resource_id = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
  log_analytics_destination_type = "Dedicated"
  log {
    category = "AuditEvent"
    enabled  = false

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

Use variables or rename resources as you like....

NOTE: The Metric Categories available vary depending on the Resource being used.
See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#data-factory-metrics) metrics emitted by Azure Data Factory version 2